SCTE ingestion is not working from ffmpeg
I have a .ts file which I want to ingest to transcoder for live streaming. It has video, audio and SCTE data streams in it. When I am ingesting this to an transcoder as srt feed. SCTE is not going.
Command:
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:v:0 -codec:v copy -streamid 0:0x1e1 -map 0:a:0 -codec:a copy -streamid 1:0x1e2 -map 0:d:0 codec:d:0 -streamid 2:0x1f4 -tag:d:0 31 -f mpegts "srt://address:2088"
It stream data for some time and throws error:
Stream 2, codec scte_35, is mixed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading
I am not sure if this command is correct or not. I got this upon on Google search. Can some help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
